# Enum Header Multiple Defnitions

Tags: c++, enums, header

I've got this "multiple Definitions" Error and don't know who to fix it.

header.h

```
    #ifndef HEADER_H
     #definde HEADER_H

     enum Gamestate{
         MENU,
         PLAY,
         PAUSE,
         GAMEOVER
        };
     Gamestate GAMESTATE = MENU;

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

switch(GAMESTATE){...}
```

If I put the Gamestate GAMESTATE = MENU; in the header.cpp main.cpp doesn't know the variable. If I compile it this way I get the multiple Def . Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the global variable `extern` in the header:

```
 #ifndef HEADER_H
 #definde HEADER_H

 enum Gamestate{
     MENU,
     PLAY,
     PAUSE,
     GAMEOVER
    };

 extern Gamestate GAMESTATE;

 #endif
```

and provide a definition in any of your `.cpp` files:

```
 Gamestate GAMESTATE = MENU;
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that header "header.h" is included in more than one compilation unit.

In this case variable GAMESTATE is defined in each module that includes the header.

You should declare the variable without its definition in the header the following way

```
extern Gamestate GAMESTATE;
```

and then for example in main.cpp define it like

```
Gamestate GAMESTATE = MENU;
```